# Interaction of D-Type flip-flops with SR inputs

Tags: flipflop

I've recently been testing myself on D-Type FlipFlop interactions for an upcoming test. In the picture below, I've assumed that Clock overrides reset in the resulting output, Q:

[image]

Am I correct in this assumption, or does Reset always override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical asynchronous `SET` and `RESET` inputs (which is what I am assuming you have - synchronous set and reset inputs operate differently) will cause the output to go to logic 1 (`SET`) or logic 0 (`RESET`) while they are active (they override the clock and D) and *stay at that level* until some other input causes the output to change.

In your case, the `SET` input will take Q high and \$\overline Q\$ low which will then retain that state *after the `SET` input is de-asserted* and up to the `RESET` assertion your diagram is correct.

When `RESET` is asserted, Q will go low *for at least the entire time of the `RESET`pulse* and Q will only go high after it is de-asserted *and* D is clocked in as a high.

Answer (score 1):

Generally available commercial edge triggered D-type flip-flops have overriding set and reset inputs. Your pulse diagram is wrong.

Nothing prevents one to design a custom type which behaves otherwise (=has edge triggering S and R), but I guess it's useless when preparing for a test of elementaries.